# connect to a tcpListener with a extended class of tcpClient

Tags: vb.net, sockets, networking, tcpclient, tcplistener

I’ve created a new class inherited TcpClient class that has a property named (for example) ClientName  . here is this class’s definition :

```
Public Class MyTcpClient
    Inherits Net.Sockets.TcpClient

    Private _ClintName As String

    Sub New(ByVal host As String, ByVal port As Integer, ByVal ClientName As String)
        MyBase.New()
        _ClintName = ClientName
    End Sub

    Public Property ClientName()
        Get
            Return _ClintName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            _ClintName = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I created an instant of this class and tried to connect this client to a server (TcpListener) with below code :

```
Try
    client = New MyTcpClient(ip, port , "ClientName")
Catch ex As Exception
    xUpdate("Can't connect to the server!")
End Try
```

But  every time I try to connect to the server an error occur with this massage :
“System.InvalidOperationException: The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets.”
Now , if I change  MyTcpClient to Net.Socket.TcpClient every thing will be ok.

```
Try
    client = New Net.Socket.TcpClient(ip, port)
Catch ex As Exception
    xUpdate("Can't connect to the server!")
End Try
```

Is there any way to connect to a TcpListener with an extended class of TcpClient like my class?

Comment: Did you happen to notice that your field is `_ClintName` when it should be `_ClientName`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks jmcilhinney ....

i tested your code , so now my first error is removed , but on the server side a new error occur . the error message is :
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient' to type 'ServerChat.MyTcpClient'."

the code in server side is :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim NewClient As MyTcpClient
    Listning = New TcpListener(GetMyIP, 3818)
    Listning.Start()
    UpdateList("Server Starting", False)
    Listning.BeginAcceptTcpClient(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptClient), Listning)
End Sub

Sub AcceptClient(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    NewClient = Listning.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar)
    UpdateList("New Client Joined!", True)
    Listning.BeginAcceptTcpClient(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptClient), Listning)
End Sub
```

the error occue in AcceptClient sub on first line :

```
NewClient = Listning.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar)
```

should i do any change on tcpListener object or something like that? or my attempt basically is wrong?

Comment: I suggest that you do some reading on Stack Overflow to learn how this site works.  You don't ask a new question in an answer.  You asked a question and it appears that my answer has resolved your issue.  In that case, you accept the answer and that is the end of it.  If an new issue has arisen then you create a new question.  You don't add an answer to this question that is not an answer at all.  Each thread contains one question and one or more answers and you accept the best answer.  If you solve the issue yourself then you post an answer with that solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, in the code that you say works, you're using the `TcpClient` constructor that has parameters for IP address and port number.  Now look at your derived class definition.  Does it use that constructor?  No, it doesn't.  It uses the constructor with no parameters.  That constructor does not connect because it doesn't know what to connect to.  If you expect your derived class to connect then you have to have it call a method that actually connects.  The obvious solution is to change this:

```
Sub New(ByVal host As String, ByVal port As Integer, ByVal ClientName As String)
    MyBase.New()
```

to this:

```
Sub New(ByVal host As String, ByVal port As Integer, ByVal ClientName As String)
    MyBase.New(host, port)
```

Comment: Thanks , i will try this code , i think this is the solution in 99.99999%. . Thank you very much